# trying to align treeview column with entry

Tags: c#, ubuntu, monodevelop, gtk#

[image]

Im trying to align my column with the entry above it so it has the same width. Is that possible ?

Comment: Not tried this but probably. Have you tried setting the TreeViewColumn MinWidth or FixedWidth attributes to the Width of the Entry?